# Trigger for after insert with condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table which contains GUID

```
Create table guiddata
{
   ID int,
   GUID RAW(16)
}
```

I need to create trigger like, when we insert data in this table and after insert if GUID column data null then insert system generated GUID in it.

For example in table

```
ID.   GUID
1.    WSER5TY89UIOPR5T
2
```

So when I inserted data only with ID that time using trigger system generated GUID needs to be store.

Comment: What code have you tried, and what errors have you encountered? What you want can easily be done with a simple `BEFORE INSERT` trigger (not AFTER).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean just plain trigger

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER guiddata_after_insert
BEFORE INSERT
   ON guiddata
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    if :new.GUID is null then
        :new.GUID := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(random_uuid())
    end if;
END;

/
```

like this?

If so, maybe it would be better to make `utl_raw.cast_to_raw(random_uuid())` default value for column `GUID`?

Comment: yes i just insert GUID but after insert preforms in table.

Comment: @meha, You can do it after insert too, but probably shouldn't. If you use trigger after insert, you'll need to update your table, and it is sub-optimal in terms of performance. But if you need to do so, you can see example [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_insert.php)